# How to get the inner dimension for Amiga Intuition window with GIMMEZEROZERO Flag?

Tags: amiga

I am sizing the contents of my Intuition window relative to the space available in the window.

A regular window exposes its initial dimensions via `my_window->Width` and `my_window->Depth`, however I see no analog when using a `GIMMEZEROZERO`.

Must I calculate this myself, or is there something more concrete?

Comment: Doesn't appear to have anything to do with retrocomputing.  Did you intend this for StackOverflow?

Comment: Using Lattice C v5, to develop in an emulated 16bit Amiga 500 using a ROM from 1988.

Comment: Oh, ok. Please provide system details in the question.  Not all of us know what an Intuition is, nor a GIMMEZEROZERO window, etc.  It's best if the average reader can at least understand the domain of the question, even if they can't answer it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `intuition.h` file (looking at Kickstart v2.04) defines the `Window` type to contain the following member variables:

```
/* These variables have the mouse coordinates relative to the
 * inner-Window of WFLG_GIMMEZEROZERO Windows.  This is compared with the
 * MouseX and MouseY variables, which contain the mouse coordinates
 * relative to the upper-left corner of the Window, WFLG_GIMMEZEROZERO
 * notwithstanding
 */
WORD GZZMouseX;
WORD GZZMouseY;
/* these variables contain the width and height of the inner-Window of
 * WFLG_GIMMEZEROZERO Windows
 */
WORD GZZWidth;
WORD GZZHeight;
```

I think you should be using the `GZZWidth` and `GZZHeight` variables, if you can confirm they exist in your version's `Window` type. If these variables don't exist because they were added in a later revision, then I'd assume you need to use the `Width` and `Height` for the `Window` but subtract the border dimensions (but I suspect these variables were there in v1.3).

Answer (score 5):

According to the Intuition Reference manual from Commodore, chapter 4 page 51:

> The unique feature of a Gimmezerozero window is that there are
> actually two “planes” to the window: a larger, outer plane in which
> the window title, gadgets, and border are placed; and a smaller, inner
> plane (also called the inner window) in which you can draw freely
> without worrying about the window border and its contents. The top
> left coordi­nates of the inner window are always (0,0), regardless of
> the size or contents of the outer window; thus the name
> “Gimmezerozero.”
>
> The area in which you can draw is formally defined as the area within
> the variables BorderLeft, BorderTop, BorderRight, and BorderBottom.
> These variables are computed by Intuition when the window is opened.
> To draw in normal windows with the graphics primitives (for instance
> to draw a line from the top left to somewhere else in the window), you
> have to start the line away from the window title bar and borders.
> Otherwise, you risk drawing the line over the title bar and any
> gadgets that may be in the borders. In a Gimmezerozero window, you can
> just draw a line from (0,0) to some other point in the window without
> worrying about the window borders.
>
> The Gimmezerozero window uses more RAM than other window types and
> degrades per­formance in the moving and sizing of windows. There can
> be a noticeable performance lag, especially when several Gimmezerozero
> windows are open at the same time.
>
> There are some special variables in the Window structure that pertain
> only to Gimmezerozero windows. The GZZMouseX and GZZMouseY variables
> can be exam­ined to discover the position of the mouse relative to
> the inner window. The GZZWidth and GZZHeight variables can be used to
> discover the width and height of the inner window.

Here is a [link to the book](http://datassette.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/livros/amiga_intuition_reference_manual.pdf).  The full definition of the Window stuct is shown on appendix pages B20-B21 (and corroborates Brian H's snippet of the header file).

Comment: Love that you gave a link to *the book* :-)

Comment: Hey @Geo... have you an index of the books on that site? Frustratingly http://datassette.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/livros/ doesn't work like I'd like it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.  I have PDF's of all the Amiga reference manuals as well as lovingly worn out originals on my shelf; so I just did a google search and that was the first hit I found.   You might be better off on the Internet Archive https://archive.org/search.php?query=amiga%20intuition%20reference

Comment: BTW, FWIW - It's not going to help you with Intuition at all, but if you want to really dive into the Amiga I recommend the Amiga System Programmers Guide from Abacus.  My copy is literally held together with duct tape that how much I referenced that book back in the day.  https://archive.org/details/Amiga_System_Programmers_Guide_1988_Abacus/mode/2up